# I took in a malnourished kitten; how do I stop my other cat from stealing her food?

Tags: cats, behavior, health, feeding, multi-pet-families

I took in a abandoned kitten; she is skinny, malnourished and needs to eat. I bought her kitten dry food, but my older cat keeps stealing her food. He has his own dish of food filled to the top constantly, but since I got her kitten dry food he doesn't want his food: he wants hers. I've been trying everything to keep him away from it, I even put it in a small 2 door carrier with the top door shut

Comment: Did you do any procedure to socialize the two cats with each other? I am not a cat person, but I read here often about "the new cat gets one room of the flat, the old cat is not allowed to go in". You need to separate both cats while feeding I assume... I have rabbits, one a senior and I separate them one hour in the morning and evening, to give the senior additional high-energy food. If I do not, the senior would get underweigthed or the other one overweighted